# Convert Date to Integer in netezza

Tags: netezza, aginity

Please help in converting the date field to integer in YYYYMMDD format
Date col- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS  - 2020-05-20 00:00:00
Required output - YYYYMMDD     - 20200520
IN Aginity workbench (Netezza).

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=extensions-conversion-functions

Get the date as string

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select to_char(to_date('2021-01-01 10:11:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYYMMDD') as str;
   STR
----------
 20210101
(1 row)
```

Now convert from string to integer base 10

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select string_to_int(to_char(to_date('2021-01-01 10:11:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYYMMDD'), 10) as num;
   NUM
----------
 20210101
(1 row)
```

To verify it is indeed an integer let us add 5 to it

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select string_to_int(to_char(to_date('2021-01-01 10:11:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYYMMDD'), 10) + 5 as numplus5;
 NUMPLUS5
----------
 20210106
(1 row)
```

Replace the date time string with your column in above examples.

Answer (score 1):

`to_char` would be helpful here.

```sql
select string_to_int(
    to_char(date_column, ‘YYYYMMDD’), 
     10 -- the base 
 )
...
```